# NFS Mounts - Linux/Windows Permissions

Tags: linux, windows, nfs

I'm trying to mount a NFS-Share where I need specific permissions on the linux-site and a specific user on windows-site who is able to read AND write in this NFS-share.

When I mount the share on Linux

`sudo mount -t nfs myservername:/NFSSHARE /mnt/mymountpoint`

it has the permissions 777 (drwxrwxrwx - nfsnobody). At this point the Windows user is able to read and write in this share.

I then change the permissions on Linux the way I need them in my Linux environment. After that the Windows user is just able to read in this share, no more write permissions.

How can I gain specific Linux permissions on the one site while still keeping read/write-permissions for the Windowsuser?

Do I need some more mount-options (like no_root_squash or similiar?). Unfortunately I'm a real NFS-Noob.

So I would be thankful for your help!(:

Comment: How does the Windows-User access the files?